# Adding an Response.Redirect to the same page dynamically to different Buttons on different other pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button, redirect

Ok here is my problem:
I have one class (so called Drawer) that does nothing else but creating asp.net controlls dynamically depending on the data it gets.
All works fine, except the last step which is nearly independent to the content.
There is allways one button, which should allways redirect to the same page (Booking.aspx).
I want the Event to store some data in the Session Object (for example the button id) and afterwards do the redirect.
This is my code:

```
Button b = new Button(); // Buchenbutton
b.ID = r.getId(); // storing important id
//b.PostBackUrl = "Booking" + k + ".aspx"; // ugly workaround
//k++;
b.Text = "Choose";
b.CssClass = "AccBtn"; // styling
b.Click += new EventHandler(thisRoute(b));
```

the real problem is, that in this "Drawer" class i cant acces the Session.Object at least i don't know how to... and i don't know how choose the Eventhandler dynamically from the code behind of the website that calls the Drawer. I hope anyone can understand and maybe even help me... i do have this ugly workaround for more than 6 months now.

Comment: Just remember, putting navigation information into Session will break the way "back" button works. ViewState is an ugly, but a more appropriate container for this type of information.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the session via the HttpContext.
`HttpContext.Current.Session`

Comment: when i click the buttons now it's only refreshing the website im currently on and the code of my Eventhandler seems to not get reached :(

Comment: is there any other way to store the information of which button of one site caused the redirect?

Comment: on the website the source says onClientclick="system.eventhandler"... when i click it the page gets refreshed and my code isn't executed at all... i dont get it

Comment: Looks like you've somehow tied you event to the buttons onclientClick and its been registered as a script

Comment: when i use button.click it isn't registered at all... il have a look again